# The "www" subdomain for my site is not working, how do I fix it?

Tags: dns, domain-registrar

I have a site `http://example.tk`. This is working fine. I have only an IP address for setup. Current configuration is 'A record'  --> IP address of the site.

But  `http://www.example.tk` is not opening. What should I do? My domain is registered with Freenom.

Comment: You need to create a CNAME record in your DNS that points www.xyz.tk to xyz.tk.

Comment: @closetnoc That's an answer.

Comment: @w3d Yes. You are right! Thank You. I was trying to fix a TOE key issue with Ubuntu that has disabled (still) one of the on-board NICs and stopping all network access for the server. When I get busy and focused on something, I drop a lot of turdletts (my scientific term)- this is just one.

Answer (score 3):

This just might be the shortest answer I have ever written...

You need to create a CNAME record in your DNS that points www.xyz.tk to xyz.tk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 of 2 things. You can either create a `CNAME` record for `www` pointing to xyz.tk. A `CNAME` record is essentially an alias record. The upside of this is that if you ever change to a different server, your `www` record won't need to change if you update the `A` record for `xyz.tk`. The downside is that it requires 2 DNS requests to actually update resolve the www.xyz.tk name. Itt goes once to ask for `www`, then when it's told it's an alias of `xyz.tk`, it has to go back to the nameserver a second time to get the `A` record for `xyz.tk`.

Your second option is to create an A record for `www` that simply has the same IP address as `xyz.tk`. The upside here is that it will only require a single DNS lookup instead of the 2 required with a `CNAME`. If you need to change your `A` record for `xyz.tk` at some point in the future, you'll need to update both. However this also leaves you the option of hosting your website (www) on one host, and other services on different hosts.